# Young tableaux — irreps correspondence for simple complex Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, young-tableaux

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$I have learned that Young tableaux which were originally
introduced to study the irreducible representations of finite
symmetric groups $S_n$ can be also used to study reps of $\GL(V)$ and
(via restriction) reps of $\SL(V)$ and therefore of
$\mathfrak{sl}_n \mathbb{C}$ in a very prolific way.

(**Note:** By 'prolific' I mean that that Young tableau / Schur functor approach
for a Lie algebra works as efficient as for reps of $S_n$, namely
that the Young tableaux corresponds 1-1 to finite dim irreps, the Clebsch-Gordan
coefficients of a tensor product of two irreps can be
explicitly calculated by Littlewood-Richardson rule (or another 'nice' closed combinatorial formula), etc. Essentially, that the theory of reps for $S_n$ 'know' everything about theory of reps for the considered Lie algebra)

In detail, the Young tableaux $\lambda $ are 1-1
with Schur projections $\mathcal{S}_{\lambda}$ of tensor powers of reps $V$ which in turn are 1-1 with finite irreducible
reps of $S_n$. It turns out that via these identifications the Young
tableaux are 1-1 with irreps of $\GL(V)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n \mathbb{C}$.

Now the question is what is going wrong if we try to mimic
this approach and trying to establish a similar correspondence
between Young tableaux and irreps of other 'classical' simple complex Lie algebras
$\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{so} \ \mathbb{C}$, $ 
\mathfrak{sp}_{2p} \mathbb{C} $ and the exceptional Lie algebras.

What is in detail going wrong in this attempt to generalize
the correspondence above? Naively the strategy should work
since for every irrep $V$ the induced rep on $V^{\otimes n}$
commutes with natural action by $S_n$. So irreps of both actions
are compatible with each other.

Which problems occur, if we work with other simple complex
Lie algebras than $\mathfrak{sl}_n \mathbb{C}$? Could it eg happen
that in contrast to the later there might be some different Young
diagrams / Schur functors which give isomorphic or even not
irreducible reps after applying to $V^{\otimes n}$ ?

Moreover, I read several times that in physics one uses successfully
Young tableaux for the real Lie algebra
$\mathfrak{su}_n $. The simple question is why in case of this
Lie algebra again 'everything works fine'? Is it an 'accident' or is there a deeper reason involved?

Are there any characterizations known for which Lie algebras
this Young tableau / Schur functor approach is prolific in the sense above and for which some that's not the case. And what are the main
obstructions for the failure?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but there are analogs of Schur-Weyl duality for other classical groups. For example, you might be interested in the Wikipedia page on the so-called "Brauer algebra": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_algebra

Comment: I think that you might be looking for Kashiwara's crystals and perhaps Lecouvey's papers on the topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201041, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211443, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211444

Comment: At a basic level, $\mathfrak{so}_n,\mathfrak{sp}_n\leq\mathfrak{sl}_n$, so in general $V^{\otimes m}$ can break up into more irreducible pieces. For example, let $V=\mathbb{C}^4$ then $V\otimes V=S^2V\oplus\bigwedge^2V$ as an $\mathfrak{sl}_4$ rep but $V\otimes V=S^2_0V\oplus\bigwedge^2V \oplus\langle q\rangle $ as a $\mathfrak{so}_4$ rep where $q$ corresponds to the symmetric bilinear form and spans a trivial rep while $S^2_0V $ are those elements of $S^2V$ which contract with the bilinear form to $0$.

Comment: Similarly $V \otimes V=S^2 V \oplus \bigwedge^2_0 V\oplus\langle \omega\rangle$ as a $\mathfrak{sp}_4$ rep. Another potential thing "going wrong" is that we can no longer find every representation within a tensor power of the defining representation e.g. the spin representations of $\mathfrak{so}_n$. Meanwhile $\mathfrak{su}_n$ works like $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ because it is just a real form of it so there is a 1-to-1 correspondence of representations (on complex vector spaces) of those two. Simply restrict a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ to give one of $\mathfrak{su}_n$.